# Delete Record VB2010 w/ TableAdapter

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ms-access-2010

This shouldn't be this hard...  But it's late.

I am working on a simple form, and trying to delete a record from a connected DataSource while using a TableAdapter.  Here is the SQL for the TableAdapter;

```
DELETE FROM Main WHERE (ID = ?) AND (tbl_Job_Name = ?)
```

Main is the table name, only two fields.

I am populating a ComboBox with this data, and I am using a Button to call the Delete() action like this;

```
 Private Sub btnDeleteJob_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDeleteJob.Click
    Dim deleteJobAdapter As New DCGDataSetTableAdapters.MainTableAdapter
    deleteJobAdapter.DeleteQuery(ComboBox2.SelectedIndex, ComboBox2.SelectedText)
End Sub
```

When I break the code I can see the ID value, but the SelectedText field is blank, and of course when it runs through the record is not deleted.  I would ideally like to just pass the ID of the selected record in the ComboBox to delete the record.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up using;

```
    Dim delJobID = ComboBox2.SelectedValue
    Dim delJobRowAdpt As New DCGDataSetTableAdapters.MainTableAdapter
    Dim delJobRow As DCGDataSet.MainRow
    Dim intDelete As Integer
    delJobRow = DCGDataSet.Main.FindByID(delJobID)
    delJobRow.Delete()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
deleteJobAdapter.DeleteQuery(ComboBox2.SelectedIndex, ComboBox2.Text)
```

SelectedText property:

Gets or sets the text that is selected in the editable portion of a ComboBox.

Text property:

Gets or sets the text associated with this control.

You can use the SelectedText property to retrieve or change the currently selected text in a ComboBox control. However, you should be aware that the selection can change automatically because of user interaction. For example, if you retrieve the SelectedText value in a button Click event handler, the value will be an empty string. This is because the selection is automatically cleared when the input focus moves from the combo box to the button.

When the combo box loses focus, the selection point moves to the beginning of the text and any selected text becomes unselected. In this case, getting the SelectedText property retrieves an empty string, and setting the SelectedText property adds the specified value to the beginning of the text.

Answer (score 0):

When I enter the code;

```
deleteJobAdapter.DeleteQuery(ComboBox2.SelectedIndex, ComboBox2.Text)
```

My break point shows the correct text from the record, but I did notice that the ID value is incorrect, the SelectedIndex returns a sequential number of the record itself, starting with "0".  So it looks like SelectedIndex does not return the actual ID value...

And back to the original issue, the record selected is still not deleted.